# Limit cached images

Tags: flutter

I want to implement image caching on my Flutter app.

I'm using the package `cached_network_image`

The code snippet below illustrates how I am utilizing this package:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: HttpRequestServices().getFillerImageUrl("MyCharges"),
  progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: progress.progress,
    );
  },
),
```

In addition to basic caching functionality, I want to limit the number of stored images to 400. Beyond this threshold, I want to replace the older images while maintaining a constant cache size of 400. If you have any insights or suggestions on achieving this efficiently, I would greatly appreciate your input."